Let $\tau(X)=\sum_i A_iXA_i^*$ be a CP map on $M_n$ such that $\text{Tr}(A_i^*A_j)=\delta_{i,j}$ and $\tau(I)$ is invertible.
Let $\tau$ be the Completely positive map (CP) defined as $\tau(X)=\sum_i A_i X A_i^*$ such that $\text{Tr}(A_i^* A_j)=\delta_{i,j}$ (in other words, $\{A_i\}$ forms an orthonormal set in $M_n$ with respect to Hilbert Schmidt inner product) and $\tau(I)=\sum_i A_iA_i^*$ is invertible. Let $A$ denote the $*-$algebra generated by $A_i$'s and $A'$ denote the commutant of $A$. Let us define the map $L(X)=\tau(I)^{1/2}X\tau(I)^{1/2}-\tau(X)$.
It is easy to verify that $A'\subseteq\text{Ker}(L)$. Is it true that $\text{Ker}(L)\subseteq A'$? If I do not assume, $\tau(I)$ to be invertible then I am able to produce easy counter example (viz. $\tau(X)=E_{11}XE_{11}^*$). But assuming the invertibility of $\tau(I)$, does the equality hold?
I am not able use the trace and invertible condition.
Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.
[UPDATE: I have changed L and it is more tractable]

The statement seems to be false. Consider $M_2$ and take $\tau$ to have a single term $A_1$, where $A_1$ is equal to $\operatorname{diag}(1, 2)$ normalized with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. Note that $\tau(I) = A_1 A_1^\ast = A_1^2$ is invertible. Next, $A$ is a subalgebra of the algebra of diagonal matrices. $A_1$ and $A_1^2$ are linearly independent, so $A$ in fact equals the algebra of diagonal matrices. Thus, $A' = A$. For $\ker(L)$ on the other hand, $A_1$ is positive so $\sqrt{\tau(I)} = A_1 = A_1^\ast$ and thus $L(X) = 0$ for any $X \in M_2$.
If you strengthen the conditions to $\tau$ being unital and trace-preserving then the statement is true (see Theorem 3.5 in Fixed Points of Quantum Operations by Arias, Gheondea, Gudder).
